# Auto-Loading Cmdlets as part of a Module dynamically

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

So, I was thinking: I have a lot (!) of custom cmdlets, but I don't want them to load all of them in my profile, because, naturally, that will take a lot of time. (I work fast, so my tools need to be fast.) But also, I don't want to always load them manually, because, well that's annoying. (And again ... I work fast!)

Luckily, there's a neat functionality called "Auto-Loading" which will totally solve my problem ... kind of. I just have to put my cmdlets into script modules, and they will be loaded automatically, right?

It seems though, there need to be some requirements met, for PowerShell to "detect" the cmdlets belonging to a module. The easiest way I know so far, is to simply put each cmdlet in a single ps1 file and then create a manifest somewhat like this:

```
@{
    ModuleVersion = "1.0"
    NestedModules = @(
        "Get-Something.ps1",
        "Remove-Something.ps1",
        "Test-Something.ps1",
        "Run-Something.ps1",
        "Invoke-Something.ps1",
        "Start-Something.ps1",
        "Stop-Something.ps1"
    ),
    CmdletsToExport = @(
        "Get-Something",
        "Remove-Something",
        "Test-Something",
        "Run-Something",
        "Invoke-Something",
        "Start-Something",
        "Stop-Something"
    )
}
```

This does work. But as I said .. I work fast, and I'm lazy. It would be much easier, if the module could discover its members dynamically. Basically, all ps1 files in the same folder. This would work pretty easily with some code in the psm1 file. But then, the **Auto-Loading would not work**. I understand PowerShell does need to know the exported cmdlets before hand.

Is there any other, dynamic way to do that, other than specifying them explicitly in the psd1 module manifest?

Comment: Have you tried using wildcards for exporting cmdlets?

Comment: @spicy.dll It seems, wildcards are not supported in NestedModules .. got an error. But it seems it does wor for `CmdletsToExport` which would at least solve half of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the size or organization of your module, create different modules for the different common subjects of your cmdlets, and put your functions into the `psm1` for each module. Then make sure you add the cmdlet definitions to `CmdletsToExport` in the module manifest (`psd1`). If you have a centralized feed, distributing your modules becomes easy, and if you simply want all of them at a given time you can create a top level module that lists your other modules as dependencies so they get installed when you install the top level module. Unless you have hundreds to thousands of cmdlets to export as part of a single module, you shouldn't need to worry about performance problems.

For each module you have on the `PSModulePath`, you can use wildcards in the `CmdletsToExport` and `FunctionsToExport` sections of your manifest for auto-complete to work, if you don't want to export them name by name.

Edit: Technically, you can call [Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7.1) and [Register-ArgumentCompleter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/register-argumentcompleter?view=powershell-7.1) yourself, however, you have the same problem now in that you need to add this to the `$profile` for each user or machine where you want the autocomplete to work, in addition to shipping your code there in the first place. So it doesn't really solve your issue.

Comment: I mean, you want bits of code you have previously developed to be packaged in an easily distributable way and make them available where you need them to work. Modules are the way. I don't know of an easier way than plopping your cmdlets into a single module and distributing that. I suggested breaking them up if organization is an issue, but autocomplete is dependent on one of two things: 1. Functions to autocomplete must be in a module with the exported functions manifested properly, or 2. they must be defined in the current session (either already imported modules or . sourced from a script)

Comment: Creating a module is the solution here but there's no "automagic" way for PowerShell to know what and when to import aside from defining a module appropriately and installing it, or dot-sourcing functions from a local script within one of the user profiles (or machine profiles, if you want them available to all users).

Comment: If you saw my prior comment (now deleted), I was conflating the behavior of omitting cmdlets/functions to export in a module manifest and when a module manifest is not defined but also does not explicitly call `Export-ModuleMember`. Apologies.

Comment: Basically, the idea is to include all of my custom cmdlets "on demand", without having do do much, and without too much overhead when adding more to my repo. Nobody else is really using it, just me.

Comment: Lol if you solve that problem, I'd love to hear it. Right now I've got shared code in modules at work and my own as well, in my own special module.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script module that will dynamically create a nested module manifest with all your cmdlets.

Here is an example .psm1 file:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem $PSScriptRoot -Filter *.ps1
$modules = $files | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$functions = $files | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName

$tmp = "$PSScriptRoot\tmp.psd1"
if (Test-Path $tmp) {
  Remove-Item $tmp -Force
}

New-ModuleManifest -Path $tmp -NestedModules $modules -CmdletsToExport $functions
Import-Module $tmp
Remove-Item $tmp
```

Just modify the first line to match your module's file structure.
Then you can import the .psm1 as a module.